# Postgres 10 on conflict column has same name a column in return table = ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_on_conflict (
  a INTEGER NOT NULL,
  b INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY(a)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

and function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.update_on_conflict (
  _a integer,
  _b integer
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  a integer,
  b integer
) AS
$body$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO test.table_on_conflict (a, b)
SELECT _a, _b
ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET b = EXCLUDED.b;           

RETURN QUERY
SELECT t.a, t.b
FROM test.table_on_conflict t
WHERE t.a = _a;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

Because the return table has column "a", ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET... gives the error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "a" is ambiguous 
LINE 3: ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET b = EXCLUDED.b
                     ^ 
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO test.table_on_conflict (a, b) SELECT _a, _b ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET b = EXCLUDED.b
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test.update_on_conflict(integer,integer) line 4 at SQL statement
```

Is there any way to disambiguate this whithout using the constraint name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two different solutions:

First simplify your function to a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_on_conflict (_a integer, _b integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (a integer, b integer) AS
$body$

  INSERT INTO table_on_conflict (a, b)
  values (_a, _b)
  ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE 
    SET b = EXCLUDED.b
  returning *;           

$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you do need PL/pgSQL (because you have other code in there that you didn't show us), you can declare the function as `RETURNS setof  table_on_conflict`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_on_conflict (_a integer, _b integer)
  RETURNS setof  table_on_conflict
AS
$body$
begin

  return query
    INSERT INTO table_on_conflict (a, b)
    values (_a, _b)
    ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET b = EXCLUDED.b
    returning *;           

end;  
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The separate `select` is not necessary in any case. You can directly return the result of the INSERT statement.

---

Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier. Do not put it into single quotes.

Comment: thank you for the comments. This is a simplified, trivial eaxample to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The result that my real-life complex function returns isn't necessarily the record that was just upserted and is only a subset of the columns in the table.
 
Regarding the single quotes around around the language name, I use "EMS SQL Manager for PotgreSQL" on Windows and just copied the DDL.

Comment: @Derek: then that's a clear bug in that "EMS SQL Manager". If you can neither switch to a SQL function nor use returns `setof` then the only chance I see is to rename the columns of the `returns table`

Comment: Thank you for now I am using `code`ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT table_pkey DO UPDATE SET`code`. My concern was that down the line someone could mange to change the constraint name.